# When I inherit my own GDExtension class, editor can no longer see the inheriting class

Tags: c++, godot, godot-4

I had two classes in my game, `Player` and `ShootableObject`. Both set up as such:

```
class Player : public RigidBody2D
{
private:
    GDCLASS(Player, RigidBody2D);
 ... implementation follows ...
```

```
class ShootableObject : public RigidBody2D
{
private:
    GDCLASS(ShootableObject , RigidBody2D);
 ... implementation follows ...
```

And registered as such in my module:

```
void initialize_example_module(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level)
{
    if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_SCENE)
    {
        return;
    }
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::Player>();
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::ShootableObject>();
}
```

I wanted to extract some common behavior from the two and created a third class, as such:

```
class GravityBody2D : public RigidBody2D
{
private:
    GDCLASS(GravityBody2D, RigidBody2D);
```

I then changed the inheritance of the other two:

```
class Player : public GravityBody2D
{
private:
    GDCLASS(Player, GravityBody2D);
 ... implementation follows ...
```

And added it to the exports:

```
void initialize_example_module(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level)
{
    if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_SCENE)
    {
        return;
    }
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::Player>();
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::ShootableObject>();
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::GravityBody2D>();
}
```

I now get an error that the classes are not found:

```
  Cannot get class 'Player'.
  Cannot get class 'ShootableObject'.
  Cannot get class 'ShootableObject'.
```

I can however see `GravityBody2D` in the node list:

[image]

How can I inherit my own class?

Comment: Does the order of registration matter? Do you get different results if you register the base class before the derived classes?

Comment: @DMGregory Just like you said, as I just found out while at my wits end. It makes little sense to me as if I were implementing such system, I'd collect metadata first and turn it into a tree later. I would also probably print a message if I was missing something, like a parent declaration.

Answer (score 1):

The order of registration matters, the parent classes MUST be registered first. Correct order in this example:

```
void initialize_example_module(godot::ModuleInitializationLevel p_level)
{
    if (p_level != godot::MODULE_INITIALIZATION_LEVEL_SCENE)
    {
        return;
    }
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::GravityBody2D>();
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::Player>();
    godot::ClassDB::register_class<godot::ShootableObject>();
}
```